# How to check the values of an android sqlite db table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I really have two questions: 
1/ how to read/check sqlite db table offline?
2/ Why is a sqlite table column of boolean type set to NULL?

ad 1/ I have downloaded sqlite3.exe and when i use the cmd > .dump quotes_table i see all rows like

```
INSERT INTO quotes_table` VALUES................
INSERT INTO quotes_table` VALUES................
INSERT INTO quotes_table` VALUES................
INSERT INTO quotes_table` VALUES................
etc
```

Is this correct as i was expecting to see just the values and not the queries?

ad 2/ I alter+updated the quotes_table by

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE quotes_table ADD COLUMN quoteUsed boolean");
db.execSQL("UPDATE 'quotes_table' SET quoteUsed = 0");
```

I read on http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html sqlite use 0 and 1 for boolean type so i thought putting quoteUsed = 0 should be OK, but the value reads NULL.
How can i fix this?

regards,

ps: FYI just installed SQLite manager addon for Firefox and it makes things easier

Comment: store 1 or 0 as string in DB and retrieve them using Boolean.parseBoolean(s);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1/ how to read/check sqlite db table offline?

Normally, SQLite is used with local databases, so database exists or does not exists - "offline" doesn't apply.

> 2/ Why is a sqlite table column of boolean type set to NULL?

SQLite doesn't have a `boolean` data type. It's affinity is `NUMERIC`. Check [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

`NULL` values, as in other DBMS, means nothing assigned.

> when i use the cmd > .dump quotes_table i see all rows like ...

`DUMP` is used to extract all data from database. Actually, it returns SQL statements you may use to rebuild a new database from scratch.

To get data only, use SQL queries (check [SELECT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)).

Comment: Thanks, for all the info appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

> when i use the cmd > .dump quotes_table i see all rows like
>
> ...
>
> Is this correct as i was expecting to see just the values and not the queries?

Yes, `.dump` creates the SQL that would produce an identical database.

> 2/ I alter+updated the quotes_table by
>
> ...
>
> I read on http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html sqlite use 0 and 1 for boolean type so i thought putting quoteUsed = 0 should be OK, but the value reads NULL. How can i fix this?

Nothing really wrong with the SQL. How are you reading the value?